# How to reliably create and detect a thread deadlock

Tags: java, junit, cross-platform, deadlock, mxbean

I've got a method in a tools class that should detect the existence of a deadlock during runtime:

```
/**
 * Returns a list of thread IDs that are in a deadlock
 * @return the IDs or <code>null</code> if there is no
 * deadlock in the system
 */
public static String[] getDeadlockedThreads() {
    ThreadMXBean threadBean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
    long[] vals = threadBean.findDeadlockedThreads();
    if (vals == null){
        return null;
    }
    String[] ret = new String[vals.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++){
        ret[i] = Long.toString(vals[i]);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I created a JUnit test that tests that functionality. It works well on Windows but on a Linux system the test fails 8 times out of 10. This is my test code:

```
/**
 * Tests the correct functionality of the get deadlock info functionality
 * 
 * @throws Exception Will be thrown if there was an error
 *             while performing the test
 */
public void testGetDeadlockInformation() throws Exception {
    assertNull("check non-existance of deadlock", ThreadUtils.getDeadlockedThreads());

    final String monitor1 = "Monitor1";
    final String monitor2 = "Monitor2";

    Thread[] retThreads = createDeadlock(monitor1, monitor2, this);

    String[] res = ThreadUtils.getDeadlockedThreads();
    assertNotNull("check existance of returned deadlock info", res);
    assertEquals("check length of deadlock array", 2, res.length);

    retThreads[0].interrupt();
    retThreads[0].interrupt();
    Thread.sleep(100);

    res = ThreadUtils.getDeadlockedThreads();
    assertNotNull("check existance of returned deadlock info", res);
    assertEquals("check length of deadlock array", 2, res.length);
}

/**
 * Creates a deadlock
 * 
 * @param monitor1 monitor 1 that will be used for synchronization
 * @param monitor2 monitor 2 that will be used for synchronization
 * @param waitMonitor The monitor to be used for internal synchronization
 * @return The threads that should be deadlocked
 * @throws InterruptedException Will be thrown if there was an error
 *             while setting up the deadlock
 */
public static Thread[] createDeadlock(final String monitor1, final String monitor2, Object waitMonitor) throws InterruptedException {
    DeadlockThread dt1 = new DeadlockThread(monitor1, monitor2, waitMonitor);
    DeadlockThread dt2 = new DeadlockThread(monitor2, monitor1, waitMonitor);
    DeadlockThread[] retThreads = new DeadlockThread[] {
            dt1,
            dt2,
    };

    synchronized (waitMonitor) {
        dt1.start();
        waitMonitor.wait(1000);
        dt2.start();
        waitMonitor.wait(1000);
    }
    synchronized (monitor1) {
        synchronized (monitor2) {
            monitor1.notifyAll();
            monitor2.notifyAll();
        }
    }
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    return retThreads;
}

private static class DeadlockThread extends Thread {
    private String monitor1;
    private String monitor2;
    private Object waitMonitor;

    public DeadlockThread(String monitor1, String monitor2, Object waitMonitor) {
        this.monitor1 = monitor1;
        this.monitor2 = monitor2;
        this.waitMonitor = waitMonitor;
        setDaemon(true);
        setName("DeadlockThread for monitor " + monitor1 + " and " + monitor2);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(getName() + ": Running");
        synchronized (monitor1) {
            System.out.println(getName() + ": Got lock for monitor '" + monitor1 + "'");
            synchronized (waitMonitor) {
                waitMonitor.notifyAll();
            }
            try {
                System.out.println(getName() + ": Waiting to get lock on '" + monitor2 + "'");
                monitor1.wait(5000);
                System.out.println(getName() + ": Try to get lock on '" + monitor2 + "'");
                synchronized (monitor2) {
                    monitor2.wait(5000);
                }
                System.out.println(getName() + ": Got lock on '" + monitor2 + "', finished");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // waiting
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output when running the testcase:

```
DeadlockThread for monitor Monitor1 and Monitor2: Running
DeadlockThread for monitor Monitor1 and Monitor2: Got lock for monitor 'Monitor1'
DeadlockThread for monitor Monitor1 and Monitor2: Waiting to get lock on 'Monitor2'
DeadlockThread for monitor Monitor2 and Monitor1: Running
DeadlockThread for monitor Monitor2 and Monitor1: Got lock for monitor 'Monitor2'
DeadlockThread for monitor Monitor2 and Monitor1: Waiting to get lock on 'Monitor1'
DeadlockThread for monitor Monitor1 and Monitor2: Try to get lock on 'Monitor2'
DeadlockThread for monitor Monitor2 and Monitor1: Try to get lock on 'Monitor1'
```

According to the output there should be a deadlock, so either the way I try to detect deadlocks is wrong or something else, I'm missing here, doesn't work as I expect it. But then, the test should fail all the time and not only most of the time.

When running the test on Windows, the output is the same.

Comment: Try to increase the Thread.sleep(4000) and see if it helps.

Comment: @NyamiouTheGaleanthrope The 4000 are the result of this attempt. It helped for MacOS (by increasing it to 1000) but extending it even further I see as "last resort" if there is a better solution.

Comment: Just a guess - might be related to monitor1 and monitor2 being Strings.

Comment: @AndrewS That shouldn't be a problem. The synchronization takes place on the passed references, so there can't be a mixup of internal references and non-internal ones. In that case I would expect the output being different in the way that both threads would report that they got the lock on the second monitor which isn't the case.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess.  Your use of `Thread.sleep()` seems highly dubious.  Try using some form of communication to determine with both threads are ready to be deadlocked.

Untested:

```
   private Thread[] creadDeadlock() throws InterruptedException {
      Thread[] deadLocked = new Thread [2];
      CountDownLatch gate = new CountDownLatch( 2 );
      CountDownLatch ready = new CountDownLatch( 2 );
      Object monitor1 = new Object();
      Object monitor2 = new Object();
      Runnable r1 = () -> {
         synchronized( monitor1 ) {
            try {
               gate.countDown();
               gate.await();
               ready.countDown();
               synchronized( monitor2 ) {
                  wait();
               }
            } catch( InterruptedException ex ) {
               // exit
            }
         }
      };
      Runnable r2 = () -> {
         synchronized( monitor2 ) {
            try {
               gate.countDown();
               gate.await();
               ready.countDown();
               synchronized( monitor1 ) {
                  wait();
               }
            } catch( InterruptedException ex ) {
               // exit
            }
         }
      };

      deadLocked[0] = new Thread( r1 );
      deadLocked[1] = new Thread( r2 );
      deadLocked[0].start();
      deadLocked[1].start();
      ready.await();
      return deadLocked;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The `sleep` at the end is happening after the deadlock should already be in place to make sure that the `ThreadMXBean` can get aware of the deadlock. What you're suggesting is already happening in the `run` method of the deadlock-thread by waiting on each monitor and performing `notifyAll` on them in the `createDeadlock` method.

Comment: You realize if you `wait()` you release the lock, right?

Comment: Yes, but that is covered here. Looking at the output the deadlock should be there because both threads don't output the second "Got lock on [monitorname]" which I would expect if something were wrong in that part of the code.

Comment: But I don't think it's reliable.  `waitMonitor` does nothing, really.  You hope that a thread is scheduled and runs, but you don't know for sure.  So you have to use something more definite to be certain that a thread (both threads) have arrived at a point in the code.

Comment: waitMonitor is used by the trheads to tell the calling method that they are ready to be deadlocked (`waitMonitor.notifyAll` is called after locking the first monitor).

Comment: So you think the call of `montor1.wait` should be done on a forth reference passed by the calling method instead of the "real" ones? The call of `wait` on `montior2` should never be reached due to the deadlock. I can try that (would be the least amount of changes in the existing code)

Comment: I think you should simplify the code.  `waitMonitor` does nothing useful as far as I can see.  `monitor1.wait(5000)` releases the `monitor1` lock for at least 5 seconds, giving plenty of time for a different thread to lock both monitors with no dead lock at all.  I think the execution of that code is indeterminate and subject to the whims of the scheduler, which is why it works differently on a different OS, even though you see all the print statements.

Comment: My code actually has a similar problem (it's all up to the scheduler) but I think it's as close to correct as possible considering that the idea is to create deadlock (which precludes any further communication).  If both threads signal the `ready` latch, they're at the point where they should dead lock, but it's still up to the scheduler to advance them forward and actually execute that code, hence the deadlock may not have actually happened yet.

Comment: The `waitMonitor`'s purpose is to tell the calling method that the thread is started and inside the `run` method, so it's not useless. Concerning the indeterminism: If the creation of the deadlock fails, the output should be different. I changed my code the way I asked two comments above. Let's see the outcome (will take until tomorrow, though ;-) It still works on Windows.

Comment: I can see what you're trying to do with `waitMonitor`, I just don't think it works.  Let's say you have more tasks in the system.  The "dead lock" two threads might not start running right away.  The main calling thread could execute all its code and go all the way to `Thread.sleep(4000);` without any of the "dead lock" threads running at all (all your waits time out).  So I don't think that code does anything.